# XMLHttpRequest - get value from URL and write it in a div

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a div called totalvalue.

```
<div id="totalvalue"></div>
```

I wrote a function to get value from my PHP script (on the same server).

```
function totalvalue() {
var ajax5 = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax5.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (ajax5.readyState == 4) {
totalvalue = (ajax5.responseText);
console.log(totalvalue);
document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = ajax5.responseText;

}
};
ajax5.open("GET", "totalvalue.php", true);
ajax5.send(null);
}
```

The php script does output a value.

Neither my console nor the div display the output.

Comment: did you check in the network tab of developer tools of any browser to see what happens in the ajax call

Comment: Well hello there, I see that you have created a div and an XMLHttpRequest in order to get something from a server. I don't see if you have a button or an event to call your function though. Do you want to change the text on page load??

Comment: totalvalue.php does not appear in the networks tab

Comment: +Panos I want to change the text on page load + I've a SetInterval function which will refresh the totalvalue function. No button

Comment: I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Try adding this parameter in the if section on your function: if (ajax5.readyState == 4 && ajax5.status == 200)
and let me know if that will work!!

Comment: Nope. Still blank and network tab shows no totalvalue.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
function test5() {

var ajax5 = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax5.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (ajax5.readyState == 4) {
xxx5 = (ajax5.responseText);
console.log("this is the total value: "+xxx5);

if (xxx5 == 0) {
document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML="Loading...";
} else {
document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML="Total: "+xxx5;
  }

 }
   };
  ajax5.open("GET", "totalvalue.php", true);
   ajax5.send(null);

  }
```

I presume that where I write the div matter + there could have been an issue with the cache. I cannot tell for sure why the above just started working.

Answer (score 0):

For simpler code, and better cross browser support, i would use jQuery.ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'totalvalue.php',
  success: function(data){
    $('#totalvalue').html(data);
  }
});
```

Read more about it in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you but I'm not using JQuery.